# Calling template function pointer with variable argument number

Tags: c++, templates

I want to write a function that calls another function with its arguments. See how I want that it work:

```
int sum(int a, int b) { return a + b }
int succ(int a)       { return a + 1 }
int size(char* str)   { return strlen(str) }

int call(???) { ??? }

int main() {
  cout << call(sum, 1, 2) << endl;
  cout << call(succ, 41) << endl;
  cout << call(size, "teste") << endl;
}
```

Expected output:

```
3
42
5
```

How can I write the `call` function (assuming that the return value is always the same)? The only way that I can think is this:

```
template<typename T> int call(T func, int a, int b) { return func(a, b) } 
template<typename T> int call(T func, int a)        { return func(a) } 
template<typename T> int call(T func, char* a)      { return func(a) }
```

Is there any way to solve this repetition with templates, `va_list` or anything else?

Intention:

It's for drawing geometry pictures, parsing a function with the parametric equation to be drawed. Example:

```
Vector2i circle(float t, float radius) {
  return Vector2i(cos(t * 2*PI) * radius, sin(t * 2*PI) * radius);
}
// ...
draw(circle, 10);
```

The function `circle` will be called many times inside `draw` with diferents `t`s (between `0.0` and `1.0`). The others arguments of draw is sent directly to the funcions, `10` will be `radius`. (Vector2i is a custom class).

Comment: just curious, why don't you just call the function(s) directly? This obtuse diversion does not seem to serve any purpose.

Comment: Can you explain the problem you're actually trying to solve rather than a perceived solution?

Comment: If you have a compiler that supports variadic templates you could do this, but the question remains ... why do you want to do this? Why not just call the functions directly?

Comment: Just use `boost::bind` (`std::bind` in 0x). And don't ever use `va_list`, it's non-type-safe cumbersome crap.

Comment: It's for drawing geometry pictures, parsing a function with the parametric equation to be drawed. Example: `Vector2i circle(float t, float r) {return Vector2i(cos(t*2*PI)*r, sin(t*2*PI)*r)};` and then `draw(circle, 10)`, where the function will be called many times with diferents `t`s (between `0.0` and `1.0`) and the `10` as the `r`. (`Vector2i` is a custom class)

Comment: @LBg best put that clarification into your question to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

C++0x variadic templates:

```
template<typename Func, typename... Args>
auto call(Func func, Args&&... args)
-> typename std::result_of<Func(Args...)>::type
{
    return func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: -1 since he didn't ask for C++0x solution but C++ solution which is assumed on SO not C++0x.

Comment: @0A0D: Er, what? C++0x *is* C++, it's even in the name.

Comment: @Cat: Look at the Tag wiki for C++. It does not mention C++0x.

Comment: +1 because regardless of pointless bickering over whether [tag:c++0x] is assumed when someone tags [tag:c++], *this answer is useful*. @0A0D did you look at the tag wiki for [tag:c++]? It does mention C++0x.

Comment: @0A0D From the OP: "Is there any way to solve this repetition with templates, va_list **or anything else**?" (emphasis mine).

Comment: @0A0D: Well, it's a stupid downvote. We specifically mark 0x solutions as 0x to avoid confusion, but that doesn't mean it's suddenly not C++. Plus, in a year tag wiki will change to 0x AND THEN WHAT?

Comment: @Luc: It was not tagged C++0x. There is a big difference. Anything else could mean anything.

Comment: @0A0D: It's good to comment on a downvote. Always state your opinion. But it's ok that people don't agree.

Comment: @Cat: You seem to have been around a while. There are many questions tagged C++ and users are downvoted for providing a C solution (and comments follow). It's the same thing.

Comment: @0A0D: No, it's not. C and C++ are two different languages. C++0x and C++03 are the same language, only 0x is a newer revision. It's more like downvoting a Java 1.7 answer on a Java 1.6 question.

Comment: @Cat: You are proving my point. The same would apply to .NET. There are things possible in .NET 4.0 that aren't .NET 2.0. The same applies here. While it is marked as the accepted answer, common practice would be to provide the appropriately tagged answer, and that's my opinion.

Comment: @0A0D Answers can't be tagged; however the very first word of this answer is 'C++0x'.

Comment: I tagged c++ meaning the language, not the version of the language. I haven't specified a version, then I expected answers in any version. I The 3º line gives me a compile error, removing it, works. Is it part of the code? And there's missing a ";" after `return`. Anyway, it works. Thank you.

Comment: @LBg I have fixed the missing `;`, thanks. `std::result_of` should be available from `<type_traits>` (maybe your implementation doesn't have it though); it is not necessary if e.g. you know that the return type will always be the same. It's here for future proofing.

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus, @0A0D, we don't need to resort for C++0x. It can be done with simple solution.

Answer (score 3):

Add another template variable:

```
template<typename T, typename U> 
int call(T func, U a) { return func(a) } 

template<typename T, typename U, typename V> 
int call(T func, U a, V b) { return func(a,b) }
```

Comment: Yes, but I also want to make it working with any number of arguments, to call `func`.

Comment: @LBg: That's not what you asked.

Comment: the only thing you could do is pass a list of arguments with stdarg, but you would only be able to pass them as a list, not in a proper call. Unless you do a switch on the number of parameters. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h

Answer (score 2):

How about a simple `#define` for current C++ solution:

```
#define call(FUNC, ...) FUNC(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Here is [the demo](http://www.ideone.com/NCdxf). I would advise to use a better name then a generic name like `call` as you are using `#define`.

Comment: Variadic macros are introduced with C++0x (but are a common extension since they are valid C99).

Comment: @Luc, I think most of the compiler supports it. But anyways, I din't know about this fact.